# React best way to track changes to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Say I have an array of objects like this and it is stored in state:

```
interface CheckItem {
  label: string;
  checked: boolean;
  disabled: boolean;
}

const [checkboxes, setCheckboxes] = useState<CheckItem[] | undefined>(undefined);


const checkboxArr: CheckItem[] = [
{label: 'item1', checked: true, disabled: false}, 
{label: 'item2', checked: false, disabled: false}
];

useEffect(() => {
  setCheckboxes(checkboxArr);
}, [])

//should remain disabled until changes are made
//should revert to disabled if changes are undone
<Button disabled={disabled}>Apply Changes</Button>
```

I also have a button that should remain disabled until one of the original elements has been changed.

What is the best way to track changes that are made to any property of each element in the array? The array can be any length, so I would like to optimize for space/time.

Comment: What exactly do you want to "track"? As long as you're not mutating the state, React will re-render whenever the state changes, is that not enough for your situation?

Comment: I should have clarified, I have a button that needs to remain disabled if there are no changes to the original data

Comment: Why are you setting the array in `useEffect` instead of just passing it as the default value to `useState`? Why do you want a general function instead of just writing some bespoke imperative code to check the stuff you're concerned about? "The array can be any length, so I would like to optimize for space/time" this makes no sense, generally an algorithm will optimize *either* for space *or* time, and unless you have tens or hundreds of thousands of checkboxes, it won't matter in the slightest for either one. None of this makes any sense.

Comment: @JaredSmith This was a very simplified sample of what the actual code is/does. No need for a snarky and unhelpful reply.

Comment: @Sean you were apparently so busy responding to my tone that you missed my point: the code you posted is too confusing for us to figure out what its doing or what you need help with. I see that you've accepted an answer, and even that starts with a *question*, because your question isn't clear (i.e. they guessed right). We get a zillion questions per day that are low-effort or written by people who cobbled copy-pasted bits of code from the internet together with zero understanding and then post here because it doesn't work. Benefit of the doubt is rarely given. Craft your questions carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By what I can understand by your question is you want to know if someone is clicked on the checkbox or not right?

You can simply track changes by having the constant variable that you already created called checkBoxArr and compare it to a new array say tempCheckBoxArr.

So say we create an array `const [tempCheckBoxArr, setTempCheckBoxArr] = useState<string[]>([])`

This is an empty array and we can store the labels of the items in this array.

Now suppose you have an onclick function on the checkboxes.

So,

```
checkboxArr.map((checkbox) => {
  return(
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={checkbox.checked} onClick={() => handleCheckBox(checkbox.label)}/>
      </div>
  )
})
```

And the function handleCheckBox is :

```
const handleCheckBox = (label: string) => {
  if(!tempCheckBoxArr.includes(label)){
    tempCheckBoxArr.push(label)
    setTempCheckBoxArr(tempCheckBoxArr)
  }else{
    let tempArr = tempCheckBoxArr.filter((labelInclude) => labelInclude !== label)
    
    setTempCheckBoxArr(tempArr)
    
  }
}
```

By the length of the `tempCheckBoxArr.length` that we created you can then track if your button should be disabled or not and also if there are changes.

Thank you, please feel free to comment if you have questions.